# parsing words from a specific line

Tags: python, parsing, awk, sed, grep

Following is python implementation to extract specific fields from the following input file.
For the line starting with `MEMRANGE`, I would like to extract the values corresponding to keys `BASEVALUE`, `INSTANCE` and `SLAVEBUSINTERFACE` and print the result in the following format.
`value[INSTANCE]`.`value[SLAVEBUSINTERFACE]` `\tab` =`value[BASEVALUE]`

Similarly, for the line starting with `PORT`, I would like to extract the values corresponding to keys `CLKFREQUENCY` and `SIGNAME` and print the result as  `value[SIGNAME]` `\tab` =`value[CLKFREQUENCY]`

*input file*

```
       <MEMRANGE ADDRESSBLOCK="HP0_DDR_LOW" BASENAME="C_BASEADDR" BASEVALUE="0x00000000" HIGHNAME="C_HIGHADDR" HIGHVALUE="0x3FFFFFFF" INSTANCE="trimap_0" IS_DATA="TRUE" IS_INSTRUCTION="TRUE" MASTERBUSINTERFACE="M_AXI" MEMTYPE="MEMORY" SLAVEBUSINTERFACE="S_AXI_HP0_hmo"/>

        <PORT CLKFREQUENCY="90005550" DIR="I" NAME="ACLK" SIGIS="clk" SIGNAME="SYS_clk_wiz_0_clk_out1">

        <MEMRANGE ADDRESSBLOCK="HP0_DDR_LOW" BASENAME="C_BASEADDR" BASEVALUE="0x00000000" HIGHNAME="C_HIGHADDR" HIGHVALUE="0x3FFFFFFF" INSTANCE="trimap_0" IS_DATA="TRUE" IS_INSTRUCTION="TRUE" MASTERBUSINTERFACE="M_AXI_DRAM0" MEMTYPE="MEMORY" SLAVEBUSINTERFACE="S_AXI_HP0_hmo"/>
        <PORT CLKFREQUENCY="90005550" DIR="I" NAME="ACLK" SIGIS="clk" SIGNAME="SYS_clk_wiz_0_clk_out1">
```

I have tested the individual functions and they work fine. When I try to write the output of the functions to the output file, only the first function is executed and the second function doesn't execute.

```
import re

def populate_ip_address(input_file, output_file):
    print(" > writing ip address")
    for line in input_file:
        match_address = re.match(r'.*MEMRANGE .*BASEVALUE="(\w+)\".* INSTANCE="(\w+)\".* SLAVEBUSINTERFACE="(\w+)\"',line)

        if match_address:
            newline1= "\n%s.%s\t\t\t\t\t= %s" % (match_address.group(2), match_address.group(3), match_address.group(1))
            output_file.write(newline1)

def populate_clock_frequency(input_file, output_file):
    print(" > writing clock_frequency")
    for line in input_file:
        match_clock = re.match(r'.*PORT .*CLKFREQUENCY="(\w+)\".* SIGNAME="(\w+)\"',line)

        if match_clock:
            print(" >> writing clock_frequency")
            newline2= "\n%s \t= %s" % (match_clock.group(2), match_clock.group(1))
            output_file.write(newline2)

input_file = open("test.txt", "r")
with open('new.txt','w') as output_file:
    populate_clock_frequency(input_file, output_file)
    populate_ip_address(input_file, output_file)
```

expected

```
SYS_clk_wiz_0_clk_out1  = 90005550
SYS_clk_wiz_0_clk_out1  = 90005550
trimap_0.S_AXI_HP0_hmo                  = 0x00000000
trimap_0.S_AXI_HP0_hmo                  = 0x00000000
```

current output

```
SYS_clk_wiz_0_clk_out1  = 90005550
SYS_clk_wiz_0_clk_out1  = 90005550
```

Am I doing something wrong in the file access?
I am also open to answers doing the above parsing in sed, awk or grep.

Comment: The first function iterates over all the lines in the file.  The second function is at the end of the file, so attempting to iterate over the lines fails because the file has already been read.  You need to rewind, or re-open the file, or do something to reset the generator.

Comment: You might just try adding `input_file.seek(0, 0)` between the calls to the 2 functions, but this feels extremely kludgy.  (Anytime you have to seek on a file, this makes it very difficult to use the tool as a filter, and seeking should be avoided).  It would be better to refactor your code so you only read the file once.

Comment: sorry @markp-fuso, I was thinking it was clear for others on what I was trying to do as I gave an example input file, regex, and expected output. In the hindsight, that was wrong. So, I have added additional textual description as you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- lines of interest (1st field is `<MEMRANGE`  or `<PORT` ) reside on a single line (ie, they do not span multiple lines)

General approach:

- split (space delimited) fields on equal sign (`=`)
- if 1st sub-field is one of our 5 desired attributes then ...
- split the 2nd sub-field on double quotes (`"`) and ...
- store the attribute/value pair in an array
- print the contents of the array

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN               { n=split("INSTANCE|SLAVEBUSINTERFACE|BASEVALUE|SIGNAME|CLKFREQUENCY",a,"|")

                      for (i=1;i<=n;i++)                  # build associative array where
                          attrib_list[a[i]]               # indices are the desired attributes
                    }

/<MEMRANGE |<PORT / { delete val
                      for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {               # loop through space-delimited fields
                          split($i,a,"=")                 # split <attrib>="<value>" on equal sign
                          if (a[1] in attrib_list) {      # if this is one of the desired attributes then ...
                             split(a[2],b,"\"")           # split "<value>" on double quote and ...
                             val[a[1]]=b[2]               # save: val[<attrib>]=<value>
                          }
                      }
                      if ($1=="<MEMRANGE")
                         printf "%s.%s\t= %s\n", val["INSTANCE"], val["SLAVEBUSINTERFACE"], val["BASEVALUE"]
                      else
                         printf "%s\t= %s\n", val["SIGNAME"], val["CLKFREQUENCY"]
                     }
' input_file
```

This generates:

```
trimap_0.S_AXI_HP0_hmo  = 0x00000000
SYS_clk_wiz_0_clk_out1  = 90005550
trimap_0.S_AXI_HP0_hmo  = 0x00000000
SYS_clk_wiz_0_clk_out1  = 90005550
```

If order is important OP can pipe the results to `sort`, eg:

```
$ awk '... awk script ...' input_file | sort
SYS_clk_wiz_0_clk_out1  = 90005550
SYS_clk_wiz_0_clk_out1  = 90005550
trimap_0.S_AXI_HP0_hmo  = 0x00000000
trimap_0.S_AXI_HP0_hmo  = 0x00000000
```

**NOTES:**

- output is based on the single `\t` delimiter as mentioned in the textual description
- OP's expected output appears to show 2 extra tabs (`\t`) for the `trimap*` lines while OP's current code appears to show 5x tabs (`\t`)
- OP can modify the `printf` format to generate the desired number of tabs (`\t`)

Answer (score 1):

You are reading input file in first function call so there is nothing to read for second call, you should open input_file separately for each call, also consider that `open`-ing file without closing is considered bad style, therefore you should ameliorate following way, replace

```
input_file = open("test.txt", "r")
with open('new.txt','w') as output_file:
    populate_clock_frequency(input_file, output_file)
    populate_ip_address(input_file, output_file)
```

using

```
with open('new.txt','w') as output_file:
    with open("test.txt", "r") as input_file:
        populate_clock_frequency(input_file, output_file)
    with open("test.txt", "r") as input_file:
        populate_ip_address(input_file, output_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Maybe it has something to do how your file pointer for your input file is kept at the end iterating over the lines of the file.
The second function call would then not be executing any iterations if you don't set seek your file to the beginning.

Try to not pass the file instance itself, but the content of the file to your functions. That did the trick for me (in addition to use "findall" and the quote escape, instead of iterating over lines in file:

```
import re

def populate_ip_address(input_text, output_file):
    print(" > writing ip address")
    matches_address = re.findall(r'.*MEMRANGE .*BASEVALUE=\"(\w+)\".* INSTANCE=\"(\w+)\".* SLAVEBUSINTERFACE=\"(\w+)\"', input_text)
    for match_address in matches_address:
        newline1= "\n%s.%s\t\t\t\t\t= %s" % (match_address[1], match_address[2], match_address[0])
        output_file.write(newline1)
    
def populate_clock_frequency(input_text, output_file):
    print(" > writing clock_frequency")
    matches_clock = re.findall(r'.*PORT .*CLKFREQUENCY=\"(\w+)\".* SIGNAME=\"(\w+)\"', input_text)
    
    for match_clock in matches_clock:
        newline2= "\n%s \t= %s" % (match_clock[1], match_clock[0])        
        output_file.write(newline2)    
    
input_text = open("test.txt", "r").read()
with open('new.txt','w') as output_file:
    populate_clock_frequency(input_text, output_file)
    populate_ip_address(input_text, output_file)
```

In addition:

Only thing I can see is that you're not escaping all the quotation marks as I would expect to be necessary.

If I am trying on regex101.com to parse your input I get your expected output when using:

```
.*MEMRANGE .*BASEVALUE=\"(\w+)\".* INSTANCE=\"(\w+)\".* SLAVEBUSINTERFACE=\"(\w+)\"
```

https://regex101.com/r/XAEHrv/1

and:

```
.*PORT .*CLKFREQUENCY=\"(\w+)\".* SIGNAME=\"(\w+)\"
```

https://regex101.com/r/D9BnQ7/1

with global and multiline flags (g+m) to not have to iterate over the lines, like you do which I find weird...try using the "global" flag